# how to watch the address of inline function in gdb

Tags: gdb, inline

assuming I have an inline function il() implemented in the h file il.h line 123.
I have several calls to it from different locations.
in addition I have the function il2() that also calls il() and called from several different locations.

trying to print this address in gdb is not working however I can see this function in backtrace and debugging like regular function , what is the address gdb shows and how does it knows to show it as function.

Answer (score 0):

gdb shows inline function like other functions but the inline function doesn't really have an address you can refer to
what gdb does is "marking" every address in the code when the inline function is pasted to and showing it as a call in the backtrace ( it is not a real call in the backtrace since the inline function code is just pasted several times and there is no really jump to function in the code )

if you plant a breakpoint at il() by:
*b il()*
gdb will tell you this is "multi" breakpoint as it actually plant a breakpoint in every call to il() from the code.
you can see these addresses by the command
"info breakpoint"
this will show all the addresses where the code "calls" ( actually pasts ) il().

**HOWEVER:**
this will not show all potential addresses that this function will appear in backtrace!
Assuming we called il2() the backtrace will be:
`il()`  : address you wont get by planting breakpoint at il()
`il2()` : some address

if you want to get all potential addresses of il() you must plant the breakpoint in the .h file
this will give you every potential address of il() in the code including calls from other inlines or MACROS
you can quickly see it by the same way ( info breakpoints )